# the coproduct in category of normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory

Let $E_1$ is subspace of normed space E and $in: E_1 \to E$ is inclusion morphism. If there exists right inverse $j$ to inclusion that is $j \circ in = \mathbb{id}$ then   coproduct $E_1 \oplus \ker{j}$ is isomorphic to $E$ in category of normed spaces.

I've been trying to prove it all day and still have no idea.

Comment: The author says it's easy, I guess just have to notice something obvious.

Comment: What have you tried? This is well-known in the case of vector spaces ("splitting lemma"), but the proof works verbatim for additive categories.

Comment: @ HeinrichD I tried to use somehow universal property (I've proved the converse proposition this way) and tried to come up with some inequality to show  that the norm on $E$  is equivalent to the norm of direct sum (coproduct) $\|z\|' = \|x\| + \|y\|$ where $x \in E_1$, $y \in \ker{j}$

Comment: @HeinrichD I am not sure, but looks like I've just figured out how to do that using only commutative diagrams. But I wouldn't call it easy.

Comment: @ Владислав: You meant to write "left-inverse" instead of "right inverse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direct way is to consider the following maps:
$$E\to E_1\oplus\ker j\quad e\mapsto (j(e),\ e-in\circ j(e)) \\
E_1\oplus\ker j\to E\quad (e_1,u)\mapsto in(e_1)+u$$
and verify that they are inverses to each other.